# Create has one polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

In my Rails 4 Application, my Developer model has one user, eg:

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :account
  ...
end
```

And in my User model I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
end
```

When the a developer record is created I would like a user to be created automatically that is associated with the developer. Is this possible? Or is there a way to do this following rails guidelines?

Comment: Yes, you could do this in the controller or with a callback (after create for example). Have you tried that?

Comment: I'd do that in the Developer model, usingthe after_creae callback with something like `self.create_user`. But it's really not obvious why do you need to use a polymorphic association in the first place, when you could just use a one-to-many association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on how you are creating a developer and where the attributes for the user are coming from. If the developer attributes are coming from a form, I'd recommend using accepts_nested_attributes_for on the Developer model. Here is some info about how to use nested attributes http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html